# Using a column value in a calculation for a nested SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have the following SQL query:

```sql
SELECT
   (SELECT CATEGORY_NAME FROM tableA WHERE NUM_CRITERIA != 0) AS "Name",
   (numYes / (criteriaCount * numParts - numNA)) / numParts AS "Progress"
FROM (
   SELECT
      (SELECT NUM_CRITERIA FROM tableA WHERE NUM_CRITERIA != 0) AS criteriaCount,
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableB WHERE RESPONSE = 'Yes' AND ASSEMBLY_ID = 1) AS numYes,
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableB WHERE RESPONSE = 'N/A' AND ASSEMBLY_ID = 1) AS numNA,
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableC WHERE ASSEMBLY_ID = 1) AS numParts
   FROM DUAL
)
```

The goal of this query is to select columns from various tables and use the values of those columns to calculate the values of the "Progress" column.  I need the "Progress" column to do the calculation in the code for each value of the criteriaCount column.  The code compiles fine in oracle apex but when it is ran I get an ORA-01427 error because the criteriaCount query returns multiple rows.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: thios here look suspios ´(SELECT NUM_CRITERIA FROM tableA WHERE NUM_CRITERIA != 0)` have you checked it for muliple rows

Comment: Please post sample data and desired output. It’s very rare case when you really need a bunch of scalar subqueries to be in one tuple. Al least because it’s totally unscalable when you want to repeat the same calculation to multiple objects (that is depicted by the error). It would be better to use `join` and conditional aggregation, but it’s impossible to reproduce with no sample data and table structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the query for `TableA` can return multiple rows (and you want that) it cannot be placed as a *scalar subquery* together with the other ones.

You'll need to query the `TableA` directly and join the result with the other subqueries.

For example:

```
SELECT
 a.NUM_CRITERIA, 
 a.category_name as name,
 (b.numYes / (a.NUM_CRITERIA * b.numParts - b.numNA)) / b.numParts AS "Progress"
FROM tableA a
cross join (
  SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableB WHERE RESPONSE = 'Yes' AND ASSEMBLY_ID = 1) AS numYes,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableB WHERE RESPONSE = 'N/A' AND ASSEMBLY_ID = 1) AS numNA,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableC WHERE ASSEMBLY_ID = 1) AS numParts
  FROM DUAL
) b
WHERE a.NUM_CRITERIA <> 0
```